# How to get Openshift session token using rest api calls

Tags: oauth, openshift

As part of an automated tests suite I have to use OpenShift's REST APIs to send commands and get OpenShift's status. To authenticate these API calls I need to embed an authorization token in every call.

Currently, I get this token by executing the following commands with ssh on the machine where OpenShift is installed: 

`oc login --username=<uname> --password=<password>
oc whoami --show-token`

I would like to stop using the **oc** tool completely and get this token using HTTP calls to the APIs but am not really able to find a document that explains how to use it. If I use the option `--loglevel=10` when calling oc commands I can see the HTTP calls made by `oc` when logging in but it is quite difficult for me to reverse-engineer the process from these logs.

Theoretically this is not something specific to OpenShift but rather to the OAuth protocol, I have found some documentation like the one posted [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/implicit) but I still find it difficult to implement without specific examples.

If that helps, I am developing this tool using ruby (not rails).

P.S. I know that normally for this type of job one should use Service Account Tokens but since this is a testing environment the OpenShift installation gets removed and reinstalled fairly often. This would force me to re-create the service account every time with the oc command line tool and again prevent me from automatizing the process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found the answer in [this](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/issues/707#issuecomment-376317374) GitHub issue.

Surprisingly, one curl command is enough to get the token:

```
curl -u joe:password -kv -H "X-CSRF-Token: xxx" 'https://master.cluster.local:8443/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-challenging-client&response_type=token'
```

The response is going to be an HTTP 302 trying to redirect to another URL. The redirection URL will contain the token, for example:

```
Location: https://master.cluster.local:8443/oauth/token/display#access_token=VO4dAgNGLnX5MGYu_wXau8au2Rw0QAqnwq8AtrLkMfU&expires_in=86400&token_type=bearer
```

Comment: Perennialista, by any chance you know how I can resolve the same thing using postman? Bumping my head for a while in order to resolve it

Comment: As of now, this solution is still a valid answer for openshift 3.11 version. And the related document is [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/authentication.html#obtaining-oauth-tokens).

Answer (score 4):

You can use token or combination user/password. 
To use username:password in header, you can use Authorizartion: Basic. The oc client commands are doing simple authentication with your user and password in header. Like this

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic <SOMEHASH>"`

where the hash is exactly base64 encoded username:password. (try it with echo -n "username:password" | base64).

To use token, you can obtain the token here with curl:

```
curl -H Authorization: Basic $(echo -n username:password | base64)" https://openshift.example.com:8443/oauth/authorize\?response_type\=token\&client_id\=openshift-challenging-client
```

But the token is replied in the ugly format format. You can try to grep it

`... | grep -oP "access_token=\K[ˆ&]*"`

Comment: You mean I could avoid using the token and just using username/password encoded in base64 format?

Comment: Yes, you can use the username/password. However, the whole auth is based on tokens. You can also create a sa and secret, add admin role to the sa and use it's token to auth against openshift. For some automated script, it is better to use sa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't see how this is different from the answer I posted, I use username and password to obtain a token and afterwards use that token for my API calls. I also specify in the question that I want to avoid using Service Accounts.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of them worked for me. I can login with "oc login" command but these curl commands fail with the 403 error. Can anyone help me with that? P.S: My cluster version is 4.6. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**In case you are using OpenShift CRC:**
Then the URL is: https://oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing/oauth/authorize

**Command to get the Token:**

```
curl -v --insecure --user developer:developer --header "X-CSRF-Token: xxx" --url "https://oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=openshift-challenging-client" 2>&1 | grep -oP "access_token=\K[^&]*"
```

**Note:**

1. `2>&1` is required, because curl writes to standard error
2. `--insecure`: because I have not set up TLS certificate
3. Adjust the user and password developer as needed (crc developer/developer is standard user in crc, therefore good for testing.)
4. Token is per default 24h vaild

**Export the Token to an environment Variable**

```
export TOKEN=$(curl -v --insecure --user developer:developer --header "X-CSRF-Token: xxx" --url "https://oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=openshift-challenging-client" 2>&1 | grep -oP "access_token=\K[^&]*")
```

**And Use the token then in, e.g., oc login:**

```
oc login --token=$TOKEN --server=https://api.crc.testing:6443
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct url for your oauth server. In my case, I use openshift 4.7 and this is the url:

```
https://oauth-openshift.apps.<clustername><domain>/oauth/authorize\?response_type\=token\&client_id\=openshift-challenging-client

oc get route oauth-openshift -n openshift-authentication -o json | jq .spec.host
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use [@Nils Buer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70624642/535203) but as I was in `docker` image in a GitLab job, I obtained a `grep: unrecognized option: P` error (as it was using BusyBox version of `grep`). Moreover inside this container, `curl` doesn't exist, I only have `wget`.

So I ended up using BusyBox `wget` and `awk` with this script:

```bash
IDP_URL=https://oauth-openshift.<clustername><domain>
wget -O - -S --header "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "$USER_NAME:$USER_PASSWORD" | base64)" --no-check-certificate "$IDP_URL/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-challenging-client&response_type=token" 2>&1 | cat > ocp4_response.txt || grep "Location: $IDP_URL" ocp4_response.txt
OCP4_TOKEN=$(grep "Location: $IDP_URL" ocp4_response.txt | awk -F 'access_token=' '{split($2,a,"&"); print a[1]}')
```

(the `|| grep "Location: $IDP_URL" ocp4_response.txt` is used as a way to avoid exiting the script because the resolution of the `302 Redirect` ends up in a `404 Not Found` so `wget` fails with an exit code of `1`).